# How can i capture what's being played on an iOS device output audio stream and store it in an object?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Is there a way to programmatically capture what's being played on an iOS device audio output? I want to capture an audio snippet and do some data processing on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an entire library devoted to this sort of thing that [Apple built in for you called AVFoundation.](https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/)

It's extensive and sprawling, so be prepared to do some work, but you'll be able to sample and manipulate the bit-streams directly with all types of audio.

If you are trying to have your app run in the background and strip audio from another app (like iTunes) or from the phone itself, put on your black hat, hack into the private API's of iOS, and release your stuff over in the jailbroken app-store, because that sort of thing is explicitly designed to not be possible with legal and legitimate apps.